# Android webview freezes in appcache downloading event

Tags: ajax, json

Our app is working pretty good but every so often our delivery drivers report that it just sits there when they are trying to sync their data.

I can mimic what they are seeing by interrupting a sync in progress either by refreshing the page or by navigating to a new page.

In Chrome, Firefox, or IE I can just refresh the sync page and the data comes down to the device without an issue. Using webView.reload() or webView.loadURL does not do anything in the webview.

If I navigate to another page, then delete all the cookies and cached data and then re login, select a route and download - it works fine. If I delete everything in the same page and refresh the manifest - it still doesn't work.

We would like to be able to download the data without clearing the cache, any ideas?

There is a lot of logging in this code. When a sync has been interrupted - the next attempt freezes in the downloading event or the checking event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugMsg('before display sync info', false, true);
    DisplaySyncInfo();
    debugMsg('after display sync info', false, true);
    u = sessionStorage.getItem('user');

    debugMsg('after getting user', false, true);

    if (!u) {
        debugMsg('no user redirecting to login', false, true);
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }

    debugMsg('check for user', false, true);

    try {
        dataLoadedTarget = new EventTarget();
        debugMsg('eventTarget set', false, true);
        dataLoadedTarget.addListener("dataComplete", downloaddataLoadedEvent);
        debugMsg('listener added', false, true);
    }
    catch (e) {
        debugMsg('add listener error', false, true);
        debugMsg(e, false, true);
    }

});

// Bind the manual update link.
manualUpdate.click(
    function (event) {
        appEvents.html('');
        // Prevent the default event.
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        // Manually ask the cache to update.
        appCache.update();
    }
);


// Bind to online/offline events.
$( window ).bind(
    "online offline",
    function (event) {
        debugMsg('online offline', false);
        // Update the online status.
        appStatus.text( navigator.onLine ? "Online" : "Offline" );
    }
);

// Set the initial status of the application.
appStatus.text( navigator.onLine ? "Online" : "Offline" );


// List for checking events. This gets fired when the browser
// is checking for an udpated manifest file or is attempting
// to download it for the first time.
$( appCache ).bind(
    "checking",
    function (event) {
        debugMsg('checking', false, true);
        logEvent( "Connecting to Server..." );//checking manifest
    }
);

// This gets fired if there is no update to the manifest file
// that has just been checked.
    $(appCache).bind(
    "noupdate",
    function (event) {
        logEvent("In No Update event..."); //checking manifest
        //TODO some kind of warning??
        debugMsg('in app cache no update, setting to reload', false, true);
        refreshManifest();
        //              logEvent("No Updates Available<br />It appears that you have already synced this data.");
        //                $("#refreshButton").show();
    }
);

$( appCache ).bind(
    "downloading",
    function (event) {
        debugMsg('downloading', false, true);
        logEvent( "Downloading data..." );

        // Get the total number of files in our manifest.
        var test = getTotalFiles();
        debugMsg('downloading, file count= ' + test, false, true);
    }
);
```

logcat from last attempt:

11-12 13:53:07.239: I/Web Console(583): appCache set:1189

11-12 13:53:07.349: I/Web Console(583): before display sync info:1189

11-12 13:53:07.359: I/Web Console(583): DisplaySyncInfo:1189

11-12 13:53:07.359: I/Web Console(583): after display sync info:1189

11-12 13:53:07.359: I/Web Console(583): after getting user:1189

11-12 13:53:07.369: I/Web Console(583): check for user:1189

11-12 13:53:07.369: I/Web Console(583): eventTarget set:1189

11-12 13:53:07.379: I/Web Console(583): listener added:1189

11-12 13:53:07.389: I/Web Console(583): checking:1189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post which surprisingly seems to have fixed the problem. Temporarily disabling the webview cache was the key.

http://blog.divhide.com/2012/11/android-webview-update-app-cache-nicelly.html

I put this code into a refresh button click event only when the current URL is the synch page.

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);

webView.reload();

try {
    Thread.sleep(3500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.reload();
```

Comment: The link is now dead, so +1 for including the relevant code in the answer.